# Is it possible to add distribution profile to iPhone when building?

Tags: iphone, xcode, distribution, profile

I can't add one to devices in xcode organizer...
When I build the app for release, should I choose simulator or device?

Answer (score 0):

For releasing your application you can not use simulator , you have to specify device or distribution.

you can use simulator for only testing purpose in ur pc.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand the question at all. But you need to choose "Device" for distribute your iPhone App, otherwise your App gets rejected before the Review has begun or it's not possible to use it for AdHoc.

For using an AdHoc Distribution Profile you need to register your Device in the iOS Developer Portal, and add it to your AdHoc Distribution Profile. Download it and drop it on the Xcode Icon. Choose the Code Signing Identities, add the Entitlements.plist, Archive your App, drop the IPA on iTunes and install it.

If you need more infos please leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a complete tutorial for the process at iOS developer center. See: https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/distribution/index.action

Answer (score 0):

You can not add a profile directly to your device. (Actually, I don't know if you can but its of no use really). You have to SIGN your app using a profile.

You can choose either simulator or device for building for RELEASE. Though simulator build will only work on simulators and are only good for testing on it using RELEASE settings (if any).